# Hana Query Error when it is ran from B1 API

Tags: hana, sapb1

I have a query if i ran this query in HANA Studio it works fine.
Example:

```
DO
            BEGIN
            DECLARE UDTNameVar nvarchar(30);
            DECLARE UDTCodeVar nvarchar(30);
            DECLARE statement nvarchar(500);          
            UDTNameVar := 'V33_EXCHANGECODES';
            UDTCodeVar := '1';
            statement := 'SELECT * FROM "@'|| :UDTNameVar ||'" WHERE "Code" = ''' || :UDTCodeVar || '''';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :statement;
            END;
```

If the same query which is like below if i ran from B1WebAPI it is giving  error:

```
DO
            BEGIN
            DECLARE UDTNameVar nvarchar(30);
            DECLARE UDTCodeVar nvarchar(30);
            DECLARE statement nvarchar(500);            
            UDTNameVar := [%UDTName];
            UDTCodeVar := [%UDTCode];
            statement := 'SELECT * FROM "@'|| :UDTNameVar ||'" 
            WHERE "Code" = ''' || :UDTCodeVar || '''';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :statement;
            END;
```

**Error:** `<message>ERROR [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General error;1287 identifier must be declared: 1: line 6 col 27 (at pos 194)</message>`

Can any one tell me what is wrong with the query why it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating the Procedure and then calling the procedure which will execute the query given below this way it is working now.